# How effective is this Xss Filter?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, security, xss

What I did here is join every single value of the request body in a single string and then loop through each character, in case a character isn't part of accepted values then I send an xss warning, otherwise next() is called.

```
function whiteListing(req, res, next) {
    const allowedValues = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890@.,!?'
    let requestBodyValues = Array.from(Object.values(req.body).join(''))
    for (letter of requestBodyValues) 
        if (!allowedValues.includes(letter)) return res.send('-xss warning page-')
    next()
}
```

I am also using other libraries that escape html values but I am still curious about the practicality of this method. If there is a way for someone to bypass this method please tell me!

Comment: XSS cannot be prevented in general with an input filter. It is an output encoding problem. There will be instances where this is enough, and there might be ones where it's not.

Comment: Thank you, however I dont understand how someone can create an xss attack with basic letters, numbers and the ,.!? characters. like you at least need %, =, ', to create even the most basic of attack vectors.

Comment: For one, such a filter on the server-side misses DOM XSS entirely. It also misses cases when input is written into javascript (`var x  = ${myVar}` as well as `onclick="${myVar}"` and so on). You might not have an exploitable case now, but what about 3 years from now, when 10 other people changed the code? Input validation is important, but it's usually not feasible to prevent XSS that way, also partly due to input requirements.

Comment: On the other hand, only having the listed 5 special characters makes it hard to do something actually useful in general, so you're kind of right in that. But this can still become a building block in a chain of attacks, it can still be useful in a givrn place in your code, so it's not considered good practice to rely on this against XSS. One acceptable thing would I think be to partially mitigate a legacy app with this, where you don't have the capacity to actually fix it. This is much better than _nothing_.

Comment: I am also html encoding all the values after this filter is executed:  `Object.keys(req.body).forEach(key => req.body[key] = xssFilter.inHTMLData(req.body[key])) `, I am very aware that there exists no way to make a website 100% XSS-proof, however I still believe that these two filters mitigate the risk quite a lot.

Comment: Also I dont think that Reflected XSS or DOM XSS is that much of a  problem as the url is not reflected in any part of the webpage, and I haven't used functions such as eval, innerHTML and things like that in my js code.  Persistent XSS or some other injection are the things that worry me.

Comment: Html encoding input is wrong, you might need that data in places that require a different encoding, not html (like in a javascript context, xml, json, yaml, in db queries, and so on). Also reflected and DOM xss are very real and existing things, maybe lower risk then persistent, but neglecting them is a significant decision. It still might be ok in your case, only you can tell, but any decent penetration test will test for those and likely find them as vulnerabilities - and so will actual attackers.

Comment: Well I am definetely not neglecting them however most of my worries lie in the persistent xss, and as for the html encoding of input, I think that you're right, it's not wrong, but it's an impractical thing, some queries might work just fine. I probably will have to html encode only inside the template. I think that's a better idea. Thanks for the help. Wish you the best!